# Download a website using wget command to include any subdomain

Tags: subdomain, wildcard, wget

I want to download a.com with all its subdmains and not other domains
for example, I want to include x.a.com in the download and excldues others like b.com
I need to have all subdomains form a.com like x.a.com included in the downlaod but nothing from other domains.
Any idea?

wget https://a.com --domain=*.a.com